# Php form issue with submitting

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been trying to make a php form, so users can send email. But due to my lack of php knowledge at this point, this is a bit hard to solve. So i've gathered some finished snippets of code, but it still does not work.

Heres the php code that i have in a file named "submit.php"

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "example@example.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

And heres the "form.php" that i have the html form in

```
<?php include('submit.php') ?>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
              <section class="contact-form">
        <form action="" method="POST">
         <h1>Contact</h1>
         <fieldset>

         <input maxlength="30" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="John" required><br>

         <input maxlength="30" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Smith" required><br>

         <input maxlength="30" type="email" name="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required>
          </fieldset>
         <fieldset>
         <textarea maxlength="300" placeholder="Write your text here...." id="message" name="message" cols="40" rows="6" required></textarea>
         <button name="submit" type="submit">Send Message</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
        </section>
```

And also someone told me that there is no security for the form, 
"**because it does not strip html tag**"

And how to i fix that?

Comment: *"but it still does not work."* - doesn't work in what respect?

Comment: if you want to strip html tag, use htmlspecialchars()

Comment: It does not work, when i hit the submit button, no email gets sent.

Comment: too many unknowns here to give a solution. How/where are you trying to run this from, local machine or hosted site? webserver and mail installed? etc. accessing file how, `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///file.php`?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: again, add error reporting. Blank page means syntax errors.

Comment: If the page is not blank but instead displaying PHP code, it sounds like PHP may not be properly configured and your webserver doesn't know what to do with it besides serve it up to the user. Does your webhost support PHP? What is your webserver running Apache, Nginx, IIS?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server should have the Sendmail configured or a different mail server.

To strip HTML you can use `$message = strip_tags($message); $message2 = strip_tags($message2);`

Or you can use `htmlspecialchars` to convert special chars to HTML entities.

Comment: this is a comment. how do you know that for certain?

Comment: did you read the part where they say: *"but it still does not work."* ?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, many times my friends and even me tried to use `mail()` on different servers where the mail server is not configured and you cannot send the mail. This is the main cause :)

Comment: How do i configure mail server?

Comment: @SpartakusMd seems like the question is still unclear and OP hasn't responded to one of my comments under their question, in regards to how/where they're running their script from.

Comment: @erdrag what webhost do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Your form isn't submitting to the PHP script

change

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
```

Edit: I see you're including `submit.php`, so you might want to do this

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: When i change action to submit.php and click the submit button, i only end up on a white page with the php code displayed.

Comment: If the `action` attribute is empty, it's value is the current URL.

Comment: @erdrag, if you have the php code displayed, then you should check if the server has support for PHP.

Comment: How can i do that? is it on my webhost site?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax has worked for me for many years:

In `"From: $from<>\n";` the `<>` is where the name would normally go.  Leave it there even if blank.

```
$mailheaders = "From: $from<>\n";
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: No1@noone.com\n";
mail($to,$subject, $message, $mailheaders, "-fmailer@yoursite.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, in addition to adding error reporting and server configuration, your header needs additional properties.  Otherwise, the email will end up in SPAM if sent at all.  Consider added the following header information.

```
/* well formed hearder */
$headers = 'From: '.$senderemail."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$senderemail."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$senderemail."\r\n";
/* additional header */
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain;'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion()."\r\n";
```

Finally, you can use a comma delimited list in the $to attribute.  So rather than running mail() twice, concatinate your to addresses.

```
$to = "john_doe@example.com,example@example.com";
```